# Conditional formatting rules not attached to cells

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I am using PHPSpreadsheet with the following code:

```
// use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional as phpC;
// use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\ConditionalFormatting\Wizard as phpW;
private function conditionWizard($range,$value,$colour){
    $greenStyle = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Style(false, true);
    $greenStyle->getFill()->setFillType('solid')->getEndColor()->setARGB(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_GREEN);

    $wizardFactory = new phpW($range);
    $wizard = $wizardFactory->newRule(phpW::TEXT_VALUE);
    $wizard->beginsWith($value, phpW::VALUE_TYPE_CELL)->setStyle($greenStyle);

return $wizard->getConditional();
}

public function conditionEqualorNot(&$workbook){
$conditions = array();

    $range = 'E1:E900';

    $conditions = array(
        $this->conditionWizard($range,'CC1','FFFE0000'),
        $this->conditionWizard($range,'CC2','FF00FF01'),
        $this->conditionWizard($range,'CC3','FFFFFF00'),
    );

    //print'<pre>';print_r($conditions);print'</pre>';exit;

    $workbook->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($range)->setConditionalStyles($conditions);
}
```

As is hopefully obvious I am trying to apply 3 different lookup conditions to the cell range E1:E900 but for some reason, although the spreadsheet is generated there are no conditional formatting rules set. I've tried a number of different combo's but am struggling to see what is wrong?

Oddly text colour seems to be editable but not the background colour - which is what I particularly want.

Even with the https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/samples/ConditionalFormatting/02_Text_Comparisons.php#L209 sample applied, (for example on the Yellow styling) I'm only getting Blue text - no yellow background!

Answer (score 0):

By referring to official [documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#formatting-cells), you can try out with following ways :

> `getStyle()` also accepts a cell range as a parameter. For example, you
> can set a red background color on a range of cells:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B3:B7')->getFill()
    ->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
    ->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF0000');
```